# Visual Studio debugger not working for a DLL build from assembly source files?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, assembly, dll, x86-64

I'm currently using masm in a C++ wrapper to develop a `.dll` so it can be used by other applications, notably a c# one in Visual Studio 2022

However developing this way has some big drawbacks. Visual Studio has all sorts of little niggles about getting MASM working such as building properly if a file is 'included' in the asm source. Such files also cannot have break points. This means I have to resort to one large file, which is getting very unwieldy.

Its like Microsoft have given up supporting MASM, unless there's some way to build a DLL that allows debugging?

Or is there some better way to develop x64 .dlls on Windows, if there's no easy fix for the Visual Studio debugging problem?

Comment: Why can't you just have multiple asm files that you link together into a dll?  People do that with C all the time.

Comment: Example of DLL with three exported functions for 64bit Windows in pure assembler: https://euroassembler.eu/eatests/t7589.htm  

Build it with `euroasm.exe t7589.htm`

Comment: `Is there any better way to develop x64 .dlls on Windows?` - well one is to not use assembler, why do you feel you need to do that?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError That answer helps noone. You don't know what is trying to be achieved. Why waste everyone's time with such a remark?

Comment: For Visual Studio 2015 and later (maybe earlier), you can do a debug build of the assembly code based dll. In the c# program, you need to specify the debug version of the dll such as  [DllImport("c:\\xcadll\\x64\\debug\\xcadll.dll")] .  You can trace from the c# program into the assembly dll without issue. I didn't have any issues using an included file in the assembly source code.

Comment: For the dll build or any assembly code, I specify a custom build step for the x64 by right clicking on the assembly source code file name in the project. For xa.asm I specify: General / Excluded From Build: No.  Custom Build Tool / Command Line:  ml64 /c /Zi /Fo$(OutDir)\xa.obj xa.asm, and Custom Build Tool / Outputs: $(OutDir)\xa.obj .   For 32 bit builds, use ml instead of ml64. For a release build, the /Zi option is not needed.

Comment: @Peter Cordes - I essentially added an answer to the question with my comments. I don't understand why the question was closed due to being "opinion based", when in fact there is an answer, but the property settings needed to get this to work for assemble source code and having to change the c# code to call a debug version of a dll are non-obvious. I have a minimal and complete example that I could post as an answer.

Comment: @rcgldr: Yeah, there are parts of it that are a specific technical question, e.g. the problem with Visual Studio's debugger that they're having.  There are other parts that seem like asking for a software recommendation, and/or subjective about what's "better", which is probably why people closed it.  Voting to reopen since you say there is a technical solution that allows debugging.  It should probably get retitled to "how to debug an asm dll in VS" or something; I'll do that.

Comment: @PeterCordes - I'm not sure why the OP was having issues with include files in assembly code. I've never encountered this.

Comment: @BJury: It was just a humble attempt at eliminating potentially unnecessary suffering in the world.

Comment: @PeterCordes - thanks, I added an answer. I'll delete this comment later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example. I'm able to step through the c# code and into the assembly code. Directory for assembly based DLL is c:\xcadll.

xa.asm:

```
        includelib      msvcrtd
        includelib      oldnames        ;optional
        .data
        .data?
        .code
        public  DllMain
DllMain proc                            ;return true
        mov     rax, 1
        ret     0
DllMain endp
        include xb.asm
        end
```

xb.asm:

```
        public  Example
Example proc                            ;[rcx] = 0123456789abcdefh
        mov     rax, 0123456789abcdefh
        mov     [rcx],rax
        ret     0
Example endp
        end
```

Program.cs - used to call the debug version of the dll:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace Program
{
    class Program
    {
    [DllImport("c:\\xcadll\\x64\\debug\\xcadll.dll")]
    static extern void Example(ulong[] data);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ulong[] data = new ulong[4] {0,0,0,0};
            Console.WriteLine("{0:X16}", data[0]);
            Example(data);
            Console.WriteLine("{0:X16}", data[0]);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Project settings for DLL build:

Create a .dll project for the assembly (or C or C++) code:

```
project properties: Debug | x64
```

properties for xa.asm:

```
General / Excluded From Build: No
Custom Build Tool / Command Line: ml64 /c /Zi /Fo$(OutDir)\xa.obj xa.asm
Custom Build Tool / Outputs: $(OutDir)\xa.obj
```

Project settings for C# build:

Create a C# project

```
project properties: Debug | x64
```

As shown in the example code above, the C# program needs to import the debug version of the DLL.

Comment: Awesome, and you can step in xb.asm?

Comment: @BJury - yes. This is what I meant by stepping through the C# code and into the assembly code. I'm not sure why your were having problems with included assembly files, as I've never encounter this before. I tested on Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 7 Pro 64 bit and later versions shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Sorry, was away for the weekend. I dont suppose you can post your project files?

Comment: @BJury - my system has 4 hard drives, 5 partitions on each hard drive (it's multi-boot, XP, XP X64, Win 7 Pro 64 bit, Win 10 Pro 64 bit), and my project files are on partition O: setup for Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2015. I've posted the setting you need to do the debug builds.

Comment: I was missing a step, you need to enable native debugging. In 2022 thats Properties -> debug -> Open Debug Launch Profiles -> Enable native code debugging.